# How to make html elements fire effects on other elements using css

Tags: html, css

I have two collections of elements I want to make inter-dependent (binded to each other)
On the one hand I have some text links in a navigation bar, on the other hand I have some elements with references to the same links. These images have animation effects, as described below (the animation occurs when hovering the images).

I want to achieve the following behavior: when hovering over links in the nav. bar, I would like to activate the hovering effects on the images. ¿Is that possible without jQuery?

This is the style of the animated elements

```
.view-first img { 
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color:rgba(116,89,47,0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first h2 {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first p { 
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first a.info{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first:hover img { 
    transform: scale(1.1);
} 
.view-first:hover .mask { 
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
.view-first:hover p {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.view-first:hover a.info {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

This is the markup of the navigation elements

```
<nav><ul>
    <li><a href="http://users.dsic.upv.es/~margomez/">DSIC</a></li>
    <li><a href="rna/tutorial/RNA_marcos.html">RNA</a></li>
    <li><a href="ares/index.php">De Ludo Bellico</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

This is the markup for one of the images with animation effects

```
<div class="view view-first">  
    <img src="images/animage.png" />  
    <div class="mask"/>  
    <div class="content"> 
        <h2>Name</h2>  
        <p>Description</p>  
        <a href="ares/index.php" class="info">Take me there!</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

So, when hovering over elements in the navigation bar , I would like to fire the animation in the associated "view" element

For what I have read, it seems that behaviour can be achieved by using jQuery (or js). But,  ¿is it possible to achieve the same effect using pure html and css ? ¿how?

The following picture shows the layout of my page. When hovering in the elements of the navigation bar, in blue, I want to fire an animation in the pictures below.
[image: screenshot of the layout]

Comment: what exactly is the question? Screen-shot of the required result would be more easy

Comment: I have rewritten my question, trying to explain it better.

Comment: Also added a screenshot, it doesn't show the animation effects, but it doesn't matter, it works as expected. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strict answer is **no**, it is not possible to make any element x run the animation for element y when you hover over it. However, you could use pure CSS in the following situations:

1) Your focused element is a **parent** of `.view-first`

```
.y:hover .view-first { ... }
```

2) Your focused element is **adjacent** to `.view-first`

```
.y:hover + .view-first { ... }
```

3) Your focused element is a **general sibling** of `.view-first`

```
.y:hover ~ .view-first { ... }
```

Interestingly, the current proposals for CSS4 include the addition of a "subject selector", which allows you to set the "subject" in your selectors using a `!`, and thus select upwards in the DOM. (See the [current W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) - Thanks to Alohci for the link). This would also be useful for this situation, but would still not allow you to select "**anything**", the elements would have to be related in some way.

**Edit**

`Mr. Alien` points out that using the `:target` pseudo-class could be useful, if you were to allow clicking the element. Lets say you had  your HTML as

```
<a href="#spin">Start Spin</a>
<div id="spin" class="view-first"></div>
```

you could then use the target to initiate the spin, by having your CSS as:

```
.view-first:target { ... }
```

Though I'm not sure if that helps you too much.

---

**Edit 2019** - The subject selector (`!`) has been replaced with the `:has()` selector, but it's [still entirely unsupported across browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility) (5 years on!)

Comment: You are forgetting `:target` ;)

Comment: He asked for hovering events, to set the target he would have to click on something.

Comment: Thanks :) - Although not necessarily relevant I have included a way of using :target to initiate the animation.

Comment: Yea, it's good to provide an alternative, `:target` is something which many users are not aware of

Comment: Note that the article you link to about the "parent selector" has it slightly wrong. The proposal currently in [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) is for a "subject selector". This is sightly more flexible than a parent selector. For example `!section + article` would match a section element that was immediately followed by an article element.

Comment: Alohci - you mean that the "subject selector" just allows you to traverse upwards, and so you don't have to select an immediate parent? Thanks for noting, I'll change my answer.

Comment: Updated, hope that's more accurate now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will study those concepts of parent and sibling elements that are new to me so as to see if they are of use to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.view-first {    opacity: 0;
/*more properties here*/}
.myDiv:hover ~ .view-first{
    -webkit-animation: boxanimation 1.5s;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: initial;
/*more properties here*/}
```

This will work for chrom and safary, for more broser you can set the -moz for firefox, and -o for opera